# Prove that if $\gcd(a, n) = d$ then $\langle[a]\rangle = \langle[d]\rangle$ in $\mathbb Z_n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am not sure how to start this problem and hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $d$ divides $a$, so in **any** $\Bbb Z_k$ it should be clear that $[a]\in\langle[d]\rangle$, whence $\langle[a]\rangle\subseteq\langle[d]\rangle$.

The reverse inclusion doesn't generally hold, but since $d=\gcd(a,n)$, then there exist $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $d=ax+ny$, so in $\Bbb Z_n$ we have $[d]=[a][x]$, which lets us demonstrate the reverse inclusion in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

By [Bezout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), there exist $u,v$ such that $d=ua+vn$. It follows that $\langle[d]\rangle\subseteq \langle[a]\rangle$.

And since $d|a$, $[a]=k[d]$ belongs to $\langle[d]\rangle$ so the reverse inclusion holds.